# Change returned value autocomplete PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I' m completely new to javascript, php etc ... and I really need some help to finish my traineeship application.

Here is my problem.

I' m using autocomplete on a database to find a specific company.

Autocompletion returns me Label and Value with the name of the company, but i need its ID because the rest of my application uses ID.

Here is an example :

This is what i got in POST :

```js
array (size=23)
  'company' => string 'example' (length=10)
```

So i still need the name of company but instead of "example" i want to have the ID of "example".

here is my search.php :

```html
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'bsup';

if(!isset($company)) $company = '';
if(!isset($_POST['company'])) $_POST['company'] = '';

$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);


$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];


$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tcompany where name like '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY name ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

        $data[] = $row['name'];
}


//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
```

My HTML :

```js
$(function() {
    var cache = {};
    $.ajaxSetup( { type: "post" } );
    $( "#company" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {

        $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
        $("#myform").submit();
      },
      source: function( request, response ) {


        $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {

          response( data );
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Update your json to include all the data you need. For example return an array like:

```
$data[$row['ID']] = $row['name']
```

If you need more data you can do an array of arrays like

```
$data[$row['ID']] = array($row['name'], $row['whatever'])
```

If you want to suggest the ID in your autocomplete instead of the name use:

```
$data[] = $row['ID']
```

Comment: Hi dude, thanks for the reply. I' ve already tried that, but when i did, my input doesn' t show anything. Don' t know why !

Comment: That means that your json doesn't return anything or is not in the right format. Remember that in your response( data ), data needs to be an array of just strings, a string or a function, so you might want to process your response further in the javascript callback, but you didn't ask that. All you asked is to include the ID, for some reason. Also, debug your code and make sure your post returns something. If data is empty it won't suggest anything.